# MySQL for loop - Insert multiple rows with same data, different index

Tags: mysql, sql, for-loop

I'm looking for a pure MySQL method to INSERT hundreds of rows into a database. I'm working with translations for an application with a rough schema like:

```
Translations
| site ID | translation ID | translation value |
------------------------------------------------
| ...     | ...            | ...               |

Sites
| site ID | language code | ... 
---------------------------------
| ...     | ...           | ...
```

The issue is I have several hundred translations in the same language where the foreign key in the table isn't the language code (I'm working with a legacy system so I can't change this).

Is there anyway I can do something along the lines of `SET @keys = ("key1", "key2", ...)` and loop through the INSERT statements?

**Clarification:**

I have a table with translations for different sites. New sites have been added to the Sites table, and I'm now adding the translations for these.

Because the translations table is based on site_id rather than language_code, I need to add the same translations for several sites. There are around 100 translations that need to be inserted for several different site_ids and this is going to be reused further down the line so it's impractical to do it manually.

Comment: Create a temporary table with the keys in and then join to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is too long for a comment, but I don't understand the question.  This sounds more like an `update` than an `insert`:

```
update translations
    set LanguageKey = <new language key>
    where TranslationID in (key1, key2, key3 . . .);
```

If you are trying to duplicate the existing rows with a new key, you can do that with an `insert . . . select`:

```
insert into translations(LanguageKey, TranslationValue)
    select <new language key>, TranslationValue
    from translations
    where TranslationId in (key1, key2, key3, . . . );
```

Your question should really provide sample data and desired results to clarify (for others) what you want to accomplish.

Comment: It's not an update, definitely an insert as it's new data. But it's repeated since I can change the structure of the DB schema. I've updated the main question with clarification

Comment: @MattLicense . . . Does the second approach fix the problem?